# Protractor: Retrieve text from Element that shares its name with other elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, aurelia, e2e-testing

I have a `<h3>` tag that is inside a `<div>`, I'd like to be able to retrieve the text inside the `<h3>` tag, only problem is that the name of the `<div>` is used in other elements across the page. I know `xpath` is one way of doing this but I've been advised to try use a different method. Any suggestions?
This is the html

```html
<div class="box-header">
<h3>User's Balance: EUR 45,173.80</h3>
</div>
```

This is my page object file:

```js
checkReceivablesDue (receivablesDue) {
  browser.sleep(8000);
  var checkBalance = element.all(by.css('box-header> h3'));
  checkBalance.getText().then(function (balance){ 
  console.log(balance);
  });
  }
```

When I run the above, I get `[]` printed in the console, I've tried a few variations but can't get it to work.
Thanks

Comment: I think your selector expression is incorrect. Try `var checkBalance = element.all(by.css('div.box-header > h3'));`

Comment: Thanks, that is giving me output for all <h3> tags, I just need to filter it so it output the correct one

Comment: `element.all` returns an array of elements, so in your case it is returning empty array, you would have to go one level up, try to identify the html tag before your div tag and then filter it, I would require more html code so that I could help you out with the code for filtering!